# Error Fortran 90: Program received signal SIGSEGV

Tags: fortran

Éste es mi programa:

```
program ejercicio8
implicit none
real(kind=8) :: i, k, pi
integer, allocatable :: n
integer :: j
real, dimension(:),allocatable :: array
pi= 4*atan(1.0_8)

!----------------------------------------------------------------   


print*, "enter dimension n"
    read(*,*) n
    allocate(array(n))
    j=0
do while (j <= n)
    array(j) = pi+(j/n)*pi
    write(*,*) array(j)
    j = j + 1
enddo
end program ejercicio8
```

El objetivo es generar un vector de dimensión **variable n** y que a cada componente le asigne un valor de un intervalo **(pi, 2pi)**, dividiendo ese intervalo en n partes. Por ejemplo: si n=4, el vector resultaría (pi, 5/4 pi, 3/2 pi, 2pi)

Mi código compila pero al momento de arrancar el programa me sale esto:

> Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

El problema radicaba en la generación de una dimensión más como dice Alvaro, y además de la línea `integer, allocatable :: n` no era necesario reservar memoria para la n.

Answer (score 0):

Reservas memoria para un array de tamaño `n` en esta línea:

```
 allocate(array(n))
```

Pero luego en el bucle accedes a n+1 posiciones de memoria porque empiezas en 0 y continuas mientras `j` sea menor o igual a `n`:

```
    j=0
do while (j <= n)
    array(j) = pi+(j/n)*pi
    write(*,*) array(j)
    j = j + 1
enddo
```

Has reservado memoria para 4 elementos, pero intentas acceder a 5. Por ejemplo, si `n` es 4. Vas a intentar acceder a la posición en los índices 0, 1, 2, 3 y 4. Al acceder a una posición de memoria que no has reservado recibirás un error de segmentación, que es lo que ves.

O bien tienes que escribir en la memoria mientras `j` sea menor (sin el igual) a `n`, o bien tienes que hacer que j empiece en 1. No tengo experiencia con Fortran, pero si no me equivoco, es un lenguaje cuyo primer índice es 1, por lo tanto deberías optar por la segunda opción.